# How to compare two attributes, where one side contain NULL values

Tags: mariadb

I have to compare the attributes of two tables in MariaDB:

Table a:

```
ID decimal
CONTENTLENGHT varchar(20)
```

Table b:

```
ID decimal
BLENGTH decimal(10.0)
```

(data model is not mine ;-) )

The field in table b supposed contain I suppose to check against. However, it contains only NULL values.
I would like to get all miss matches returned. I executed the following command:

`select a.ID,a.CONTENTLENGTH,b.BLENGTH from a inner join b on a.ID=b.ID where cast(CONTENTLENGTH as decimal)<>b.BLENGTH;`

This command returns an empty set.

Any ideas why?

Comment: use `left join`. this here "The field in table b supposed contain I suppose to check against" needs some work, hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If the field `BLENGTH` in table `b` contains only `NULL` values, then any comparison to `NULL` using standard SQL comparison operators (like `<>`, `<`, `>`, `=`, etc.) will result in `NULL` (unknown).

This means that the condition `cast(CONTENTLENGTH as decimal)<>b.BLENGTH` will always be evaluated as `NULL` (unknown) and thus no rows will match the criteria.

To include rows where `BLENGTH` is `NULL`, you'll need to handle `NULL` values explicitly.

Here's how you can modify the query to find mismatches including those where `BLENGTH` is `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT a.ID, a.CONTENTLENGTH, b.BLENGTH
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE 
    (cast(a.CONTENTLENGTH as decimal) <> b.BLENGTH) 
    OR 
    (b.BLENGTH IS NULL AND a.CONTENTLENGTH IS NOT NULL)
    OR 
    (b.BLENGTH IS NOT NULL AND a.CONTENTLENGTH IS NULL);
```

This will give you:

1. Rows where the values of `CONTENTLENGTH` (casted to decimal) and `BLENGTH` are different.
2. Rows where `BLENGTH` is `NULL` but `CONTENTLENGTH` is not.
3. Rows where `BLENGTH` is not `NULL` but `CONTENTLENGTH` is.

This should cover all the mismatches.